# Select the value of dictionary of a vector in R

Tags: r, list

I am writing R, and I store my data with the list(or dictionary in Python),
So here's the thing I want to do:
category is given, a is given, I hope I can make the 'expected output'
(I can do it when there is only one element in a, but failed when there are multiple element in a)
Thank you for your help!

```
category <- list(
'one' = 'AA',
'two' = 'BB',
'three' = 'CC',
'four' = 'DD')

a = c('three','two')
expected output:
c('CC','BB')
```

Comment: do you have to use a list? or can you use a named vector, e.g. `category <- c('one' = 'AA', 'two' = 'BB')`. Then you can do `category[ a ]`

Comment: Could you rephrase what you are looking for? I understand you wan to acces to elements of category is that it?

Answer (score 1):

Are [] brackets what you are looking for?

```
category <- list(
  'one' = 'AA',
  'two' = 'BB',
  'three' = 'CC',
  'four' = 'DD')

a = c('three','two')
category[a]
```

Output:

```
$three
[1] "CC"

$two
[1] "BB"
```

Comment: @ting_H could you check it as correct? Thank you!

Comment: yes! This is what I want :) I clicked the helpful mark.